# Load predefined session content - is it possible and how to do it if yes

Tags: php, session, get, isset, unset

I am looking online for this the whole weekend but cannot find anything so I am starting to think it is either not possible or it is just that I cannot figure it out.

The case is the following:

There is a form on Page 1. Upon submission, the form information is stored in a `$_SESSION` and the user is directed to Page 2. There are several hundred queries on Page 2 that read the `$_SESSION` content and display certain results based on this content.

What I am trying to do is to skip Page 1, and direct the user straight to Page 2, where he could see some results that I want to predefine for him. I want to do this by loading a pre-saved `$_SESSION` data, either from a file or by placing it directly in the PHP file (is this even possible?)

Here is the code on Page 2, that I use to Get the `$_SESSION` from Page 1. What modifications should I do to it to load a session file of my choice or even better load the session content straight on Page 2:

```
unset($_SESSION);
//I add this value first to unset any previous sessions the user might have and then I am not sure how to proceed.    

if(isset($_GET['sid']) && $_GET['sid'] != ''){

    if(isset($_SESSION['pageRedirct']) && $_SESSION['pageRedirct'] != ''){
        unset($_SESSION['pageRedirct']);
    }

    $sid        = base64_decode($_GET['sid']);
    $save_srch  = $db->GetRow("SELECT * FROM ".$tblprefix."search_save WHERE id = $sid");

    $pageRedirct        = $save_srch['search_page'];    
    $_SESSION['pageRedirct']    = $pageRedirct;
```

To provide some info why I need to do this - there are several hundred variables on Page 1 that are required to properly display Page 2 so I just want to copy one `$_SESSION` and use it to directly load Page 2, instead of manually setting all required variables on Page 2 (which will take enormous amount of time).

If I am not explaining something well let me know to edit my question.

Any ideas comments will be appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: can not unset `$_SESSION` but assign an empty array. [`session_start()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) loads session data.

Comment: Yes I tried this: `session_name('session_name');
session_start();` but the session_name just does not load.

Comment: session_name is a cookie or a GET parameter name with session id. All assigned after `session_start()` $_SESSION-variables will be available every time after `session_start()` (even by default php.ini settings).